# Run function after two functions has ran

Tags: swift, async-await, structured-concurrency

So let's say I have these three functions:

```
func func_1() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        let state = try await api.get1State(v!)
        print("cState func_1: \(state!)")
    }
}

func func_2() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        let state = try await api.get2State(v!)
        print("cState func_2: \(state!)")
    }
}

func func_3() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        let state = try await api.get3State(v!)
        print("cState func_3: \(state!)")
    }
}
```

Since these function get info from api, it might take a few seconds.

How can I run `func_3`, after both `func_1` and `func_2` is done running?

Comment: @khjfquantumjj - No, because she doesn't know whether 1 or 2 will finish first. She needs to use some sort of dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise avoiding `Task` (which opts out of *structured concurrency,* and loses all the benefits that entails) unless you absolutely have to. E.g., I generally try to limit `Task` to those cases where I are going from a non-asynchronous context to an asynchronous one. Where possible, I try to stay within structured concurrency.

As [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) says:

> Tasks are arranged in a hierarchy. Each task in a task group has the same parent task, and each task can have child tasks. Because of the explicit relationship between tasks and task groups, this approach is called *structured concurrency.* Although you take on some of the responsibility for correctness, the explicit parent-child relationships between tasks lets Swift handle some behaviors like propagating cancellation for you, and lets Swift detect some errors at compile time.

And I would avoid creating functions (`func_1`, `func_2`, and `func_3`) that fetch a value and throw it away. You would presumably return the values.

If `func_1` and `func_2` return different types, you could use `async let`. E.g., if you're not running `func_3` until the first two are done, perhaps it uses those values as inputs:

```swift
func runAll() async throws {
    async let foo = try await func_1()
    async let bar = try await func_2()

    let baz = try await func_3(foo: foo, bar: bar)
}

func func_1() async throws -> Foo {
    let foo = try await api.get1State(v!)
    print("cState func_1: \(foo)")
    return foo
}

func func_2() async throws -> Bar {
    let bar = try await api.get2State(v!)
    print("cState func_2: \(bar)")
    return bar
}

func func_3(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) async throws -> Baz {
    let baz = try await api.get3State(foo, bar)
    print("cState func_3: \(baz)")
    return baz
}
```

Representing that visually using “Points of Interest” tool in Instruments:

[image]

The other pattern, if `func_1` and `func_2` return the same type, is to use a task group:

```swift
func runAll() async throws {
    let results = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Foo.self) { group in
        group.addTask { try await func_1() }
        group.addTask { try await func_2() }

        return try await group.reduce(into: [Foo]()) { $0.append($1) } // note, this will be in the order that they complete; we often use a dictionary instead
    }
    let baz = try await func_3(results)
}

func func_1() async throws -> Foo { ... }

func func_2() async throws -> Foo { ... }

func func_3(_ values: [Foo]) async throws -> Baz { ... }
```

There are lots of permutations of the pattern, so do not get lost in the details here. The basic idea is that (a) you want to stay within structured concurrency; and (b) use `async let` or `TaskGroup` for those tasks you want to run in parallel.

---

I hate to mention it, but for the sake of completeness, you can used `Task` and *unstructured concurrency.* From the [same document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) I referenced above:

> **Unstructured Concurrency**
>
> In addition to the structured approaches to concurrency described in the previous sections, Swift also supports unstructured concurrency. Unlike tasks that are part of a task group, an unstructured task doesn’t have a parent task. You have complete flexibility to manage unstructured tasks in whatever way your program needs, but you’re also completely responsible for their correctness.

I would avoid this because you need to handle/capture the errors manually and is somewhat brittle, but you can return the `Task` objects, and await their respective `result`:

```swift
func func_1() -> Task<(), Error> {
    Task { @MainActor [v] in
        let state = try await api.get1State(v!)
        print("cState func_1: \(state)")
    }
}

func func_2() -> Task<(), Error> {
    Task { @MainActor [v] in
        let state = try await api.get2State(v!)
        print("cState func_2: \(state)")
    }
}

func func_3() -> Task<(), Error> {
    Task { @MainActor [v] in
        let state = try await api.get3State(v!)
        print("cState func_3: \(state)")
    }
}

func runAll() async throws {
    let task1 = func_1()
    let task2 = func_2()

    let _ = await task1.result
    let _ = await task2.result
    let _ = await func_3().result
}
```

Note, I did not just await `func_1().result` directly, because you want the first two tasks to run concurrently. So launch those two tasks, save the `Task` objects, and then `await` their respective `result` before launching the third task.

But, again, your future self will probably thank you if you remain within the realm of structured concurrency.